# transformations from a sphere using R for raster and polygon data

Tags: raster, polygon, r, coordinate-system, modis

I am planning on using the MODIS burned area products which were produced by Maryland University. These come as either polygons or rasters. In the user guide it says

A shapefile version of the MCD45 product is derived from the monthly Geotiff version by the University of Maryland. The shapefiles are available with the same projection (Plate-Carrée) and geographic extent as the Geotiff sub-continental windows

I used the following code in R to convert the projection from sphere-based datum to WGS 1984 UTM ZONE 38N (into the same projection as the rest of my data, including the dem data).

Is the code below correct for converting these projections?

```
library(raster)
projection(fire) <- projection(dem)
```

How would I do this for polygon data?

Comment: That code won't work - it will **assign** a new projection, but won't **transform** it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Project raster**

```
projectRaster(fire, crs = projection(dem), method = "ngb")
```

**Transform shapefile coordinates** (assuming the polygons are in `fire_shp`)

```
spTransform(fire_shp, CRS = CRS(projection(dem)))
```